# Autocomplete Dynamic Form (jQuery) - The same class to all input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

Im'm using the following code (HTML Form) :

```html
<form id="forma2">          
    <table id="prodItems" class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">

              <!-- ENCABEZADOS -->
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                     <th style="width:8%">Partida</th>
                      <th style="width:8%" >Cantidad</th>
                      <th style="width:15%">Modelo</th>
                      <th style="width:15%">S/N</th>
                      <th style="width:70%">Descripcion</th>
                      <th style="width:3%">Check</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <!-- FIN ENCABEZADOS -->
                  <!-- INGRESO DE DATOS DE PRODUCTOS -->
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                       <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="n_cantidad" id="cantidad" maxlength="5" placeholder="#"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control autocompletModelo" name="n_modelo" id="modelo" maxlength="20" placeholder="XXX-XX" type="text"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="n_serie" id="serie" maxlength="20" placeholder="12345"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="n_descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="300" placeholder="Descripcion del Material"/></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type='checkbox' class='check'/>
                            </div>
                        </td>                   
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <!-- FIN  INGRESO DE DATOS DE PRODUCTOS -->
            </table>
        <!-- FIN TABLA -->

                <!-- BOTONES APP--> 
                <input id="crearNuevo" type="button" class="nuevo" value="Crear Nueva">
                <button type="button" class="agregar">Agregar Campos</button>
                <button type="button" class="borrar">Eliminar Campos</button>
                <input type="reset" class ="reiniciar "name="reset" id="button" value="Restablecer Campos" />
                <input id="enviarDatos" type="button" class="guardar" value="Guardar">
                <!-- FIN BOTONES APP -->
                <p>
                <div class="enviartodo">
                        <div class="confirmacion"></div>        
                 </div>
</form>
```

I'm using jQuery to:

-Add new row to the table (It's Works)
-Delete row (It's Works)
-Autocomplete the input text "Modelo" (It's Works)
-Autocomplete the input text "Descripcion" with the query from "Modelo" (It's Works)

```js
$(function() {

    $(".autocompletModelo").unbind().autocomplete({
        source: "auto-modelo.php",
        minLength: 2,
        autoFocus: true
    });
 
$(".autocompletModelo").focusout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'auto-descripcion.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{ modelo:$('.autocompletModelo').val()}
        }).done(function(respuesta){
            $("#descripcion").val(respuesta.descripcion);});
    });
});

// FIN AUTOCOMPLETAR MODELO - DESCRIPCION 


//FUNCION AUTOCOMPLETAR CLIENTES

$(function() {
    
    $("#empresa").autocomplete({
        source: "auto-clientes.php",
        minLength: 2 
    });                
});

// FIN FUNCION AUTOCOMPLETAR CLIENTES

$(function() {
    var count = 1;
  
   $(".agregar").on("click",function() {  
   count++;
      newRow = '<tr><td>'+count+'</td><td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_cantidad" id="cantidad" maxlength="5" placeholder="#"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control autocompletModelo" name="n_modelo" id="modelo" maxlength="20" placeholder="XXX-XX" type="text"></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_serie" id="serie" maxlength="20" placeholder="12345"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="n_descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="300" placeholder="Descripcion del Material"/></textarea></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" class="check"/></div></td></tr>';
      $('#prodItems tr').last().after(newRow);
   });
  
   $(".borrar").on('click', function() {
  $('.check:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
       
          });
   
});
```

The problem is that only Works with de First Row in the table. If I need to try add new Row, Autocomplete is not workking :S.

Some idea ?

Thanks You.

Comment: Just a quick comment: it is not necessary wrap each function with `$(function() {  })`, just wrap them all with it.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? Please

Comment: Take a look on the JSFiddle that is on my answer. There all the functions are wrapped inside a unique `$(function() { })`

Comment: It's done all functions are wrapped inside a unique $(function() { }) . I will try again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your new rows are dynamically generated so at the moment when you first bind the `autocomplete` and `focusout` those rows don't exist.

So the solution is simple: bind `autocomplete` and `focusout` after you create each row. You can replace your add function with this one:

```
$(".agregar").on("click",function() {  
      count++;
      newRow = $('<tr><td>'+count+'</td><td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_cantidad" id="cantidad" maxlength="5" placeholder="#"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control autocompletModelo" name="n_modelo" id="modelo" maxlength="20" placeholder="XXX-XX" type="text"></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_serie" id="serie" maxlength="20" placeholder="12345"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="n_descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="300" placeholder="Descripcion del Material"/></textarea></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" class="check"/></div></td></tr>');
      $('#prodItems tr').last().after(newRow)

      newRow.find(".autocompletModelo").autocomplete({
          source: "auto-modelo.php",
          minLength: 2,
          autoFocus: true
      }).focusout(function(){
          $.ajax({
                url:'auto-descripcion.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data:{ modelo:$('.autocompletModelo').val()}
          }).done(function(respuesta){
                $(this).parents("tr").find("#descripcion").val(respuesta.descripcion);});
          });
      });           
});
```

Here is [JSFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7L4azqn/1/) with an example.

Comment: I´m trying with the example, but not works on my server :( . I don't understand what happend ..

Comment: It's Works dude ! But I need to add each description to each model like in the first row.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Using the same idea explained earlier, you can bind again the focus out. **IMPORTANT:**  Adding new rows will create elements with repeated `ids`, please change them to `classes` and edit your code accordingly. `Ìds` should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".agregar").on("click",function() {  
        count++;
        newRow = '<tr><td>'+count+'</td><td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_cantidad" id="cantidad" maxlength="5" placeholder="#"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control autocompletModelo" name="n_modelo" id="modelo" maxlength="20" placeholder="XXX-XX" type="text"></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" name="n_serie" id="serie" maxlength="20" placeholder="12345"/></div></td> <td><div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" rows="2" name="n_descripcion" id="descripcion" maxlength="300" placeholder="Descripcion del Material"/></textarea></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><input type="checkbox" class="check"/></div></td></tr>';
        $('#prodItems tr').last().after(newRow);
        $('.autocompletModelo', newRow).autocomplete({
            source: "auto-modelo.php",
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: The same result dude, only works with the first row. The second row failed to load autocomplete function.